# Python subprocess not working with OpenVPN

Tags: python, subprocess, openvpn

I'm trying to use a subprocess to connect to openvpn. The command works fine when I enter it directly into the terminal, however, it does not work inside a subprocess command for some reason.

Code:

```
import subprocess

# use shell command to connect openvpn
r = subprocess.Popen(['openvpn', '--config', 'config.ovpn'], shell=True)
```

Which returns a generic response from openvpn like:

```
General Options:
--config file   : Read configuration options from file.
--help          : Show options.
--version       : Show copyright and version information.
... 100 more lines of help info
```

It doesn't seem to be adding the config options.

Any idea why?

Comment: What's the response when you run it from terminal?

Comment: @EricJin Managed to fix it. I used a string instead of a list for the command and it worked.